# Check if a map between group is an isomorphism

Tags: group-theory

I wanted to prove that the following map

\begin{align}
\Phi_a : (\mathbb{R},+) &\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},+)
\\x&\mapsto x+a
\end{align}

is a group isomorphism, but I started to have some perplexities doing simple calculations:

First, I start to compute the kernel $Ker\Phi_a = \{x \in \mathbb{R} 
\, | \, x+a =0 \}$, but what I apparently find is that the set $\{-a\}_{a \in \mathbb{R}} \in Ker\Phi_a$.

Then, I also tried to check if the operations are preserved:

$$\Phi_a(x+y) = x+y+a \neq \Phi_a(x)+\Phi_a(y) = x+a+y+a$$

So is it possible that the map is neither a group (endo)morphism?

Comment: A group isomorphism sends neutral element to neutral element. So $\Phi(0)=0$ is demanded for group isomorphism $\Phi:(\mathbb R,+)\to(\mathbb R,+)$.

Comment: this means that for $a \neq 0$ this will never be a group isomorphism?

Comment: Correct. It is an isomorphism if and only if $a=0$.